# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘transpose’ with no type [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

Beginner coder having trouble with my code

my Matrix.h file

```
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
    private:

        vector<vector<int> > M;
        unsigned int ROWS;
        unsigned int COLS;
        bool operationIsValid(const Matrix &, const string&) const;

    public:

        //Constructors
        Matrix();
        Matrix(const string&);
        Matrix(int,int,int);

        //Accessors
        const Matrix transpose() const;
        ....   
};
```

my Matrix.cpp file

```
#include "Matrix.h"
....

using namespace std;

//Constructors
Matrix::Matrix() {
    vector<vector<int> > A(3, vector<int>(3, 0));
}


//Accessors
const Matrix::transpose() const{
    vector<vector<int> > B = A;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3;j++) {
                A[i][j] = B[j][i];
            }
        }
}
.....
```

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong so any feedback would help!
first time posting so formatting is wrong.

Comment: Read that line after the “Accessors” comment carefully. It’s a common kind of typo.

Comment: Lot of matrix question in the last few minutes. Assignment due?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const Matrix transpose() const;   // declaration from header
const Matrix::transpose() const   // definition from cpp file
```

It looks like you've just added in the `::`. Unfortunately that means the return type has now *disappeared* since you've appropriated it for the class specifier.

You will need the definition to be:

```
const Matrix Matrix::transpose() const { ... }
//    ^^^^^^
// (return type)
```

---

The reason *why* you need to do this follows. When you are declaring the class (inside the `class classname { ... }` bit), you don't actually need to specify the class name because, well, it's implicit. So you would do it so:

```
class classname {
    void function(int param);
}
```

But *outside* of the declaration, where you want to define what `function` actually does, you need a way to tell the compiler which class it belongs to. So you *explicitly* specify the class:

```
void classname::function(int param) {
    weaveMagicWith(param);
}
```

In your case, you used the following declaration and definition (spaced out so you can see the equivalent bits):

```
const Matrix transpose()         const;
const        Matrix::transpose() const { weaveMagic(); }
```

What you *should have done is to just replace `transpose()` in the first line with `Matrix::transpose()` in the second. By simply adding the `::` *without* the classname, you've effectively removed the return type altogether, leading to your error message (with my addition of the emphasised bit):

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'transpose' with no ***[return]*** type

---

It's no different really to using the declaration/definition pair:

```
const int giveMeSeven();
const     giveMeSeven() { return 7; }
```

whereas the *correct* variant of that second line would be:

```
const int giveMeSeven() { return 7; } // with the 'int'
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my problem! If you don't mind can you explain this concept a little more to me?

Comment: @Yao, as requested. See the update, hopefully that fleshes it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is missing a return type in your .cpp file.

This line:

```
const Matrix::transpose() const{
```

should be:

```
const Matrix Matrix::transpose() const{
```